# How to make a Dev/Debug version of my app, without overriding the production version on the device

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, testing, xcode5

I have an AppStore installed app which I installed on my iPad.
Let's call it App123.

I'm busy developing a new version which I want to test on my device, but the "dev" version connects to a server on the local LAN and I still use the production version regularly.

How can I deploy a "dev" or "debug" version of my project to the device without overriding the AppStore one?

Do I need a different bundle identifier? A new provisioning profile?
Also I would like the App's name on the device to be "App123(dev)"

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change the bundle id to be different from the productive version, you will get the development version installed next to the productive one.
To change the name, simply rename your target in XCode.

hope that helps,
kind regards, 
Peter

Comment: Hi, I only got around to trying this now. I'm not succeeding though. I renamed my bundle identifier by adding a ".dev" to the end and I think I renamed my target. Can you give me an indication where in XCode you would change these so that I can validate what I've tried so far?

Comment: Ok, seems I had to build for a different scheme, overlooked that. It's working now. Thanks again!